# Javascript Object Persistence

Tags: javascript, object, closures

How do I do the following whilst protecting the state of b?

```
var a = function(o){
  this.o = o;
  this.o.one = 'three';
}
var b = {'one':'two'};
var c = new a(b);

console.log(b.one);  //three
```

I realize that this works...

```
var a = function(o){
  this.o = {};
  this.o.one = o.one;
  this.o.one = 'three';
}
...
```

but what if I would like to 'import' the whole object?

EDIT

This is answered here -> [JavaScript: How to pass object by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7574054/javascript-how-to-pass-object-by-value)

Thanks everyone!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  You could use a closure to "protect the state".  Is your goal to create a class-like structure?  If so, you can create a constructor function.  More details about what you are trying to accomplish would help.

Comment: Template objects that contain html and css shortcode anchors which are combined to create differently styled things to present to the client, but my template objects kept getting altered.

Comment: Sounds like you may want to look into a databinding framework for JavaScript:  KnockoutJS, AngularJS, and Ember are all good.

Comment: The question title is totally misleading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to copy `b`. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/728694/31158) for the idea and some caveats.