# Javascript passing by reference instead of value?

Tags: javascript, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

Hello and thanks for help

When I was writing some code I ran into a problem. In the example below. I was expecting the `alert(a.x)` to output 1, instead it outputs 2. I have come to learn that it is because `a` is being passed to `this.b` as a reference. What I cannot seem to find, is how to pass it instead by value. (As in, I don't want to modify `a` every time I call `x()` )

```
var a = {"x":1}

function x() {
  this.b = v;
  this.b.x++;
}

x();

alert(a.x); //prints 2
```

I have also tried the following and other variants to no avail...

```
var a = {"x":1}

function x(v) {
  this.b = v;
  this.b.x++;
}

x(a);

alert(a.x); //... still prints 2
```

Can anyone clue me in on what I am missing?

Please and Thank You

(sidenote: [this is a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568966/how-do-i-pass-the-value-not-the-reference-of-a-js-variable-to-a-function) that got to close to what I am talking about, but I couldn't figure out how to make it apply to my situation... if it is the same situation at all)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you call:

```
x(a);
```

A few things are going on.  First, the variable `a` (which simply holds a reference to an object) is passed *by value* to the function `x`.  `x` now has its *own copy* of that reference, which happens to point to the same object in memory.  Thus, any changes you make to properties on that referred object will affect other references to said object.

When you call:

```
this.b = v;
```

You're again making a copy of `v` and setting it to `this.b`.  Now, `a`, `v` and `this.b` are distinct variables in memory, all storing a reference to the same object.

It seems what you're *attempting* to do is create a copy of the object itself, so you can manipulate one reference and not affect others.  To do so, you'll need to create a *completely new* object in memory and copy over the properties.

```
var a = {"x":1}

function x(v) {
    this.b = {}; // Create a new object
    this.b.x = v.x; // Copy over the x property
    // Copy over any other properties too
    this.b.x++;
}

x(a);

alert(a.x); // The original object still has an x property of 1
```

Since `this.b` is a new object and we've merely *copied over* properties from the object referred to by `v`, incrementing `this.b.x` will have no effect on whatever `v` is pointing to.

Comment: By reference means assignments are visible to caller, here just mutations are visible to caller. Caller will not see mutations in non-objects because you cannot mutate them anyway. It is always pass by value.

Comment: By *reference*, I meant one copy of the object will exist in memory, and a *reference* to that location will be passed around.

Comment: @mike. In your first example, why is it, that when you pass `a.x` into `x(v)` that you can set `this.b.x = v.x` as opposed to just `this.b.x = v`? Does that question make sense?

Comment: @bobkingof12vs - You can't.  The parameter `v` is equal to a numeric value (1 in this case).  A numeric value *has* no `x` property (if you accessed it, you would just get `undefined`)

Comment: I guess my question is more, In your example: `function x(v) {
  this.b = v;
  this.b.x++;
}` where do you get `this.b.x` from?

Comment: @bobkingof12vs - Oh, that was a mistake on my part.  I copy and pasted your code and forgot to update that line.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks for the correction

Comment: No. "Objects" cannot be passed because they are not values. Objects are always manipulated through *references* (pointers to objects).

Comment: @Esailija - I've updated my answer to further clarify *exactly* what's being passed around.  My answer now seems overwhelming but it's a lot more accurate now.

Answer (score 0):

So maybe I can provide you with some clarity by breaking down what's happening.

```
var a = {"x":1} // a refers to object with key "x"

function x(v) {  // v is now a reference to the object with key "x"
  this.b = v;   // this.b now is a reference to the object with key "x"
  this.b.x++;   //this.b.x++ points to the object with key "x" so it can increment it's value.
}

x(a);  // passes in a the value of reference to object with key "x"

alert(a.x); //... still prints 2
```

You can do something that could be found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7574054/javascript-how-to-pass-object-by-value) link:

```
var o = {};
(function(x){
    var obj = Object.create( x );
    obj.foo = 'foo';
    obj.bar = 'bar';
})(o);

alert( o.foo ); // undefined
```