# Passing a copy of a data property to a function in Vue JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a simple vue instance that I'm using to generate a Stripe token.

It looks like this:

```
var vm = new Vue({
        el: '#checkout-form',
        data: {
            stripe_publishable_key: '{{ config('services.stripe.publishable') }}',
            card: {
                number: null,
                cvc: null,
                exp: null,
            },
        },
        ready: function() {    
            Stripe.setPublishableKey(this.stripe_publishable_key);
        },
        methods: {
            getStripeToken: function() {
                Stripe.card.createToken(this.card, this.stripeResponseHandler);
            },
            stripeResponseHandler: function(status, response) {
                // Process response
            },
        },       
    });
```

Basically I pass the `card` object in my Vue instance (which is bound to some form inputs) to Stripe's `card.createToken` method. This should take the input and call the handler, passing in the response as it does so.

This all works fine except that `card.createToken` is modifying the card object and causing the card object on my Vue instance to change - it inserts its own properties and causes strange behaviour on the bound `<inputs>`.

Is there a way to pass the `card` vue property to Stripe as a copy which is unbound to the vue instance and thus won't change as a result?

**Update**

In essence this is happening because JavaScript passes objects as a [copy-of-a-reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7574054/javascript-how-to-pass-object-by-value) which means the original object can be modified by any function that receives it. The obvious solution is to clone the object by looping or some other means but I was wondering if there's a better way in Vue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many ways to make a copy of this object, but only one from Vue itself:

`var cardCopy = Vue.util.extend({}, this.card);`

It is actually an equivalent to jQuery's extend with deep set to true.

Comment: seems like the most concise method, albeit this problem seems a little hacky to fix

Comment: @harryg it's undocumented built in function but it's accessible so we can use it ;)

Answer (score 1):

Not that I know much Vie.js but is `this.data` is simply a JavaScipt object then you could clone it with this:

```
function cloneObject(obj) {
  var clone = {};
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
    clone[key] = obj[key];
  });
  return clone;
}
```

Or in ES3 land:

```
function cloneObject(obj) {
  var key, clone = {};
  for (key of obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key) {
      clone[key] = obj[key];
    }
  }
  return clone;
}
```

But this is a shallow clone so objects that are properties of the `obj` would not be cloned but their references would be the same (allowing mutation).

jQuery (if you have that) also provides a convenient way to do this:

```
var clone = $.extend({}, this.data);
```

And finally as @oleg-melashko pointed out Vue.js has a `Vue.util.extend` as well (though the [documentation](http://vuejs.org/api/) seems to lack any reference to this).

```
var clone = Vue.util.extend({}, this.data);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also copy the card object like below

```
let cardCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.card));
```

Answer (score 0):

There is coerce hook function for properties in Vue 1.0.12

It can be used for creation of object clone like that (ES6)

```
import _ from 'lodash';
export default{
    props: {
        myObjProp: {
            type: Object,
            coerce(val) {
                return _.clone(val);
            }
        }
    }
};
```