# Javascript push into array without reference

Tags: javascript, arrays, shadow-copy

This is super frustrating to me so I hope someone can help. The below is a small example to illustrate my problem.

```
var group = {
    names: []
}
var groupList = {
    group: [],
    activity:[]
}

$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#play").click(function(){

        var soccer = group;

        var person = "Jack";
        soccer.names.push(person);

        var person = "Amber";
        soccer.names.push(person)

        groupList.group.push(soccer); //group[0]

        // how do I make a constructor for a new group?
        var soccer1 = group;
        var person = "Jill";
        soccer1.names.push(person)

        groupList.group.push(soccer1); //group[1]

        // expect group 0 to be [Jack,Amber] (but pushing Jill on group1 updates group0)
        $("#beta").append("Soccer Group: "+groupList.group[0].names +"<br/>");

         // expect group 1 to be either [Jack,Amber,Jill] or [Jill]
        $("#beta").append("Soccer Group: "+groupList.group[1].names +"<br/>");

    });

});
```

I need to create a new instance of group without changing the original group.

https://jsbin.com/hetenol/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript: How to pass object by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7574054/javascript-how-to-pass-object-by-value)

Comment: You can use spread operater for clone

Comment: Let copiedGame ={...Game}

Comment: Var copiedGame = JSON.parse(json.stringify(Game));

Comment: By convention, only capitalize constructor functions. So change to `var game ... `

Comment: It's worth mentioning that you're talking about an `object`, not an `array`, which is where the problems come in: https://medium.com/@fknussel/arrays-objects-and-mutations-6b23348b54aa

Comment: `AllGames.Games.push( JSON.parse( JSON.stringify( Game ) ) );` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: The following will only work if you plan to fill the arrays `Game.player` and `Game.score` with primitives.

---

You could clone the arrays like this:

```
AllGames.games.push({
  player: [...Game.player],
  score: [...Game.score]
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator

Comment: See OP at _"When I push the Game onto AllGames, I want it to copy and not reference Game."_

Comment: Unless you want to modify `Array.prototype.push`, I don't see that happening.

Comment: I understood the OP's question as asking, copy Game by value, instead of by reference.

Comment: At the code at Answer if a value is changed at the original object the value will be changed at the object within the new array.

Comment: @guest271314 I appreciate that your reputation is so high, but I have to disagree with you here. When I run this code and change a value of the original array, the newly created object retains its value. Can you explain?

Comment: `var Game = {
    player: [{abc:123}],
    score: []
}; var AllGames = {
    Games: []
}; AllGames.Games.push({
  player: [...Game.player],
  score: [...Game.score]
});Game.player[0].abc = 345; console.assert(AllGames.Games[0].player[0].abc === 123, [AllGames.Games[0].player[0]])`

Comment: For some reason I assumed the arrays player and score were to contain primitive values not objects. I will edit my answer to be more specific. Thanks

Comment: Can you show me how to do the Clone with this example? https://jsbin.com/hetenol/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 1):

Solution to the question:

var soccer1 = jQuery.extend(true,{}, group);

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function called "group" as a constructor.

```
function group() {
    this.names = [];
}

var groupList = {
    group: [],
    activity:[]
}

$(document).ready(function(){

$("#play").click(function(){

    var soccer, soccer1, person;

    soccer = new group();

    person = "Jack";
    soccer.names.push(person);

    person = "Amber";
    soccer.names.push(person)

    groupList.group.push(soccer); //group[0]

    soccer1 = new group();
    person = "Jill";
    soccer1.names.push(person)

    groupList.group.push(soccer1); //group[1]

    // expect group 0 to be [Jack,Amber]
    $("#beta").append("Soccer Group: "+groupList.group[0].names +"<br/>");

     // expect group 1 to be [Jill]
    $("#beta").append("Soccer 1 Group: "+groupList.group[1].names +"<br/>");

    });

});
```