# React Native : Change on a variable also change other variable's value where it is previously assigned to it

Tags: react-native

I've added a button to call this function

```
onPress(){
    if(!this.data) this.data = this.test;
    else for(var i in this.test) this.data.push(this.test[i]);
    console.log(this.test.length);
}
```

On the first call `this.test` is assigned to `this.data`. I suppose it is passed by value not by reference. So when the iteration change the value of `this.data`, it will not affect `this.test`.

But I am wrong. `this.test`'s value is changed. I know the workaround is I should avoid to assign it directly. Define `this.data = []` in constructor first. And iteration is the only way. But is it supposed to work that way or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays and Objects are always passed by reference. Only primitive types are passed by value.

You could make a copy of the object by stringify to JSON and parse again:

```
this.data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.test));
```

Comment: ok thank you sir. absolutely. i've tried it on browser to find it out

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are wrong. Arrays in JavaScript are stored by reference consider the code below

```
a = []
b = a
b.push(1)
console.log(a) //will logout [1]
```

If you want to create a new copy of the array you can do something like

```
a =[1, 3, ]
b = [...a]
b.push(4)
console.log(a)
console.log(b)
// This logs a as [1,3] and b as [1, 3, 4]
```

However, if the first array has some value that is stored by reference, for example, an array or an object that value will as well be modified if its modified in B i.e

```
a = [ [2], [4]]
b = [...a]
b[0].push(5)
console.log(a) // logs out a as [[2,5], 4]
```

One simple solution to solve that will be using JSON.stringify and JSON.parse i.e

```
a = [ [2], [4]]
b = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a))
b[0].push(5)
console.log(a) 
console.log(b)
// logs out a as [ [2], [4]] and b as [[2,5], 4]
```

However, if the data you are working with is too much JSON.stringify and JSON.parse become expensive operations and you might want to look at something like [immutablejs](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/List) or look at an alternative to create deep copies of such data structures. Hope this helps

Comment: ok tq sir. i follow this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7574054/javascript-how-to-pass-object-by-value